# Sort frame by key descending in Deedle

Tags: c#, sorting, deedle

I'm trying to sort a `Frame` by the keys in Deedle. There is a method available to do this in ascending order (`SortRowsByKey`), but I need it in descending order. I'd rather not have to rip apart and recreate the frame just to do this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I have had success using the `Frame.RealignRows()` method. It will order rows based on the order of the Rowkeys provided. Combine `RealignRows()` with `RowKeys.Reverse()` and you should get the desired result!

```
df = df.RealignRows(df.RowKeys.Reverse());
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to sort and reverse your results. Bad news is - `Frame` does not support reversing. Good news is - `Series` does support reversing. And each of your columns in the frame is a series.

So to sort in descending order these are the steps:
1. Sort the frame.
2. Revers each column.
3. Use the reversed columns to build a new frame.

```
// Sort the data frame by ColumnA
var sorted = dataFrame.SortRows("ColumnA");

// Build a new frame
var reversedFrame = 
    Frame.FromColumns(new[] 
    {
        sorted["ColumnA"].Reversed, 
        sorted["ColumnA"].Reversed, 
        sorted["ColumnA"].Reversed
    });
```